# How to convert minutes to hours & minutes in PHP and negative minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, time, date-arithmetic

I have looked everywhere but cant find a specific answer that can help me.

I am trying to work this out. We have a system in place where staff can accrue and use time in lieu. So in a MySQL DB im recording the amount of minutes, and weather it is added or removed.

I then have a function which calculates the amount of minutes currently owed to staff or business which can result in negative numbers occasionally - if the staff members owes the business time.

I use this function to then convert the total minutes to Hours and Minutes. However when there is say -15 minutes, the function returns as -1hr -15mins. I understand the reason that this is happening but cannot work out a way to stop it.

```
function convertTime() {
$args = func_get_args();
switch (count($args)) {
    case 1:     //total minutes was passed so output hours, minutes
        $time = array();

        $time['hours'] = floor($args[0]/60);

        $time['mins'] = ($args[0]%60);
        return $time;
        break;
    case 2:     //hours, minutes was passed so output total minutes
        return ($args[0] * 60) + $args[1];
}
}
```

I appreciate any assistance at all!!

Comment: what is the return of `func_get_args()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nicely mentioned in a [comment on the php documentation of `floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php#79515), you should use the [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function in order to achieve rounding towards `0` for every integer.

So change you line for hours calculation to the following:

```
 $time['hours'] = intval($args[0]/60);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that floor rounds *down* what you want to do is round *towards zero*. As far as I know, there's no single function to do this, but this would work:

```
function convertTime() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    switch (count($args)) {
        case 1:     //total minutes was passed so output hours, minutes
            $time = array();

            $time['hours'] = $args[0] > 0 ? floor($args[0]/60) : ceil($args[0]/60);

            $time['mins'] = ($args[0]%60);
            return $time;
            break;
        case 2:     //hours, minutes was passed so output total minutes
            return ($args[0] * 60) + $args[1];
    }
}
```

I added a ternary operator that basically says "if the minutes is greater than zero, round the hours down. Otherwise, round the hours up (towards zero)."

**Edit:** use @s1lence's answer instead!